# Filter the form choices visible in the browseable API

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am using a filter to apply object level permissions to a collection. Resources in a second collection have a many-to-many relationship with the first. On the browsable API, when creating resources in the second collection, the user is presented with a list of resources from the first to link it to. However, this list is not filtered, so the user can see values that they should not be able to see.

I've poked around the documentation and source a bit and I cannot see a way to add filtering to the queryset that generates the choices without overloading or modifying a bunch of code to pass the request data down (probably removing some of the collection specific data on the way) and then apply the filters.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: I really think this is a security flaw. So I suggest: don't use the browsable api in production environments.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there's nothing to support this out of the box. Pull requests are always welcome. If it's something you want to work on you may want to either [open a ticket on GitHub](http://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues) or [hit up the mailing list](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/django-rest-framework) to discuss it first.

Comment: It's on my to-do list. When I get to it, I'll open a ticket. :)

Comment: is this supported now ?